# Use Secure Store Credentials to connect to database with Windows Authentication in Visual Studio solution?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, bcs, external-content-type

**Background:** I have an external content type that has been developed in a Visual Studio 2010 solution. This content type is based mostly off elements in a database that are accessed via stored procedures. This works fine on my local machine, using pass through authentication (as BCS seems inclined to do for VS solutions) but I'm having issues when moving onto our organisations development server.

I'm trying to find details on how I can:

1. Access the SS credentials from within a C# solution.
2. Use these credentials for Windows Authentication with an `SqlConnection` object.

I'm the first person in my organisation to be doing anything with BCS, so there's no established procedure or way of doing this.